# Django South - Change CharField to ForeignKey

Tags: django, django-models, django-south

I have a setup like this currently.

```
#models.py
class Donate(model.Model):
             item_locations = models.CharField(max_length=150)
#forms.py
    ItemChoices = (('item1','item1'),('item2','item2'),('item3','item3'))
    class DonateForm(ModelForm):
         item_locations = CharField(choices=ItemChoices)
         class Meta:
              model = Donate
```

I want to change item_locations to a ForeignKey and let the users be able to alter the item list on their own. I have made another class called ItemLocations and changed it to

```
item_locations = models.ForeignKey(ItemLocation)
```

How do I make it so that the database can keep the previous records? Donor1 has a item location of "Item1", how do they keep that data after changing it to a foreign key where the lookup will be 'item_location_id'?

Also, is this as simple as a south migration? My DB is MySql.

```
./manage.py schemamigration donate --auto
```

Answer (score 3):

Simplest way is to:

1. Add the new foreign key column.
2. Migrate the data over using `get_or_create`.
3. Delete the old column.

You can speed things up by precalculating things and using an `update` query.